# I created a 32-bit program, but Windows 7 Home Basic claims it is 16-bit and thus cannot run

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, 16-bit

I currently maintain a 32-bit application created in the .NET framework.

Some of the users of said application recently reached out to me saying that the application could not run on their installations of Windows 7 64-bit, one of which claimed to be running Home Basic.

This is a screenshot of the error:

[image]


This is strange, because it is running perfectly fine on my installations of Windows 10 64-bit Home and Pro. Other users use my application on their installations of 64-bit Windows 7 without issue, and that has been the case for almost a year.

Furthermore, when I locate the process in Task Manager, it does say the process name followed by `(32 bit)`. Therefore, I am quite lost on why my users' Windows 7 installations are seeing my app as a 16-bit app.

Comment: It is not possible for a .NET application to be a 32-bit application.  I assume the executable in the screenshot, is actually the name of the executable, for your application?  Based on the information, the behavior you describe, cannot be explained.  Please edit your question and provide the necessary information required to answer it.

Comment: @Ramhound The name of the executable isn't the name of the executable in the screenshot. The screenshot, according to the user, is what pops up when they try to open my program (presumably it's a system popup or a .NET popup). The user does have the required .NET framework version.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer this question.  Without the name of the executable, and without ruling out if it's a custom 16-bit application, but it is literally not possible for .NET applications to be 16-bit.  So it does not make sense that, your .NET application, would be connected to a 16-bit application.  *Is there any connection to the executable being called out to your executable?*